# How to decrease step of XF86KbdBrightnessDown and XF86KbdBrightnessUp handlers on Ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, notify-osd, keyboard-accelerators

My hardware supports full 256 steps of screen brightness. Unfortunately Ubuntu's default brightness driver uses wrong steps: I need to increase granularity of steps in the dark end of the spectrum, and decrease on the bright end.

The following script `bright.sh` demonstrates how I'd like the brightness to be handled:

```
#/bin/bash
sciezka="/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"
if [ "$1" == "+" ]; then
    maxbright=`cat $sciezka/max_brightness`
    bright=`cat $sciezka/brightness`
    bright=`echo "print(int(min($maxbright,$bright + max($bright * 0.5, 1))))" | python`
else
   if [ "$1" == "-" ]; then
    bright=`cat $sciezka/brightness`
    bright=`echo "print(int(max(0,$bright - max($bright * 0.33, 1))))" | python`
   fi
fi
echo $bright | sudo tee $sciezka/brightness
```

How do I **replace** the `XF86KbdBrightnessDown` and `XF86KbdBrightnessUp` handler with my custom one? I'd like to keep this cool OSD slider, but use my logic for the actual brightness adjustment.